# Slicknav Below Header

Tags: html, css, slicknav

How can I get `slicknav` to appear below my header on my site the link of what I did is below I'm having trouble figuring

[Fallen-Wings](http://www.fallen-wings.com)

Comment: Your question should be self contained. [edit] it and include the relevant parts of your HTML and CSS. Also make a screenshot (with annotations?) of what it is and should be. You don't have enough reputation yet to include pictures in your question, but you can post it on an image hosting website and include the link here.

Comment: What did you tried so far? What problem did you face?

Comment: My issue was getting the slicknav menu bar to appear below the header when it displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code after your header in html :

```
<nav id="menu-mobile"></nav>
```

Create a new file .js with this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $('#menu').slicknav({
        prependTo:'#menu-mobile'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have horizontal navigation instead of vertical? Try:

```
#navbar ul li {display: inline;}
#navbar a {display: inline-block;}
```

and remove float and width properties for #navbar.